# the y-axis is crazy

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

i have this graph where the axis is wrong! the y-axis is separated..
I think that it's wrong  "axis x line" and "axis y line",but i can't fix it

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,  xmin=460.46, xmax=4604600,ymin=0,ymax=1.15,xlabel style= 
{above right},ylabel style={above right},ylabel = {$Ganancia [Veces]$}, xlabel={$Frecuencia 
[Hz]$},ytick = {1,0.9,...,0.1}, xtick={460.46,4604.6,46046,460460,4604600},xticklabels= 
{$460.46$,$4604.6$,$46046$,$460460$,$4604600
$},grid=both]%grid=both toda la cuad.
\addplot [blue,domain=1:4604600,samples=1000] {(1/(2*pi*x*0.000001))/((sqrt((3.456)^2+ 
(1/(2*pi*x*0.000001))^2))};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

thanks!

Comment: try `axis lines=left,` instead yours `axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,`, However, you also need to remove error in your function expression.

Comment: Don't work! :((

Comment: Sorry, but this work! See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

**Edit:**
Is now better?

[image]

After correcting error in your function expression (missed is one `)`), removing axis labels style (as are defined, x label overlap diagram), the code for MWE, which produce above diagram, is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    axis lines=left,
    xmin=460.46, xmax=4604600,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.15,
    ylabel={\textit{Ganancia} [\textit{Veces}]}, 
    xlabel={\textit{Frecuencia} [Hz]}, 
    ylabel style={at={(-0.1,1)}, anchor=south east},
    xlabel style={at={(1,-0.1)}, anchor=north east},
    ytick = {1,0.9,...,0.1}, 
    xtick={460.46,4604.6,46046,460460,4604600},
    xticklabels={$460.46$,$4604.6$,$46046$,$460460$,$4604600$},
    grid=both]%grid=both toda la cuad.
%
\addplot [blue,domain=1:4604600,samples=100] 
    {1/(2*pi*x*0.000001)/(sqrt((3.456)^2+(1/(2*pi*x*0.000001))^2))};
\end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the x label and y label near the arrows as it was on my graph..

Comment: Well, you like to have there. Just define their style properly, now is used their default positions. I will show you how to write correct style (as I guessing how you like to have)  asap.

Comment: It's very well! THANKS!